# Como usar la clase TimeUnit en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio que me pide crear un metodo que dada una cantidad de Segundos, el programa lo exprese en Dias, Horas, Minutos y Segundos. Encontre este codigo en StackOverflow:

```
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day *24);
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - 
(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds)* 60);
long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds) - 
(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) *60);
```

pero no puedo usar `TimeUnit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TimeUnit pertenece al paquete java.util.concurrent. TimeUnit ha llegado en java desde jdk 1.5. TimeUnit juega con la unidad de tiempo. TimeUnit tiene muchas unidades como DAYS, MINUTES, SECONDS etc.

```
TimeUnit tu=TimeUnit.DAYS;
```

TimeUnit es un enum. Cuando llamamos TimeUnit.DAYS o cualquier otra unidad, devuelve TimeUnit. TimeUnit tiene un método de conversión que puede convertir el valor largo dado en la unidad de tiempo requerida. TimeUnit ha timedJoin. Normal juntar función en java, espera un hilo hasta que el hilo termine su trabajo, pero timedJoin espera sólo hasta un momento y luego el control de las versiones de hilo de llamada.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.timedJoin(th, 5);
```

este es un ejemplo de código completo.

**TimeUnitTest.java**

```
package com.GilbertoQuintero;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class TimeUnitTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException{
        TimeUnit tu=TimeUnit.DAYS;
        long noOfDays=tu.convert(48,TimeUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println("noOfDays:"+noOfDays);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        Thread th=new Thread( new TimeUnitTest().new RunnableThread());
        th.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.timedJoin(th, 5);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
  //runnable thread
    class RunnableThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int cnt = 0;
            for (; cnt < 5;cnt++ ) {
                System.out.println("run:" + cnt);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```